# KeyboardHookProc in DLL doesn't do anything when called from python

Tags: python, c, winapi, dll, hook

I've been trying to write a DLL in C.

Install hook sets up the KeyboardProc. Calling the `InstallHook()` and `UninstallHook()` functions from Python always returns a 0, which I guess is because my callback function `KeyboardProc` isn't working.

The following is my C code for the DLL:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ourdll.h"

//#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.SHARED,RWS")
//#pragma data_seg(".SHARED")
HHOOK hKeyboardHook = 0;
int keypresses = 0;
    HMODULE hInstance = 0;

//#pragma data_seg()

BOOL WINAPI DllMain (HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwFunction, LPVOID lpNot)
{
            hInstance = hModule;  //Edit
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int hookCode, WPARAM vKeyCode, LPARAM flags)
{
    if(hookCode < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook, hookCode, vKeyCode, flags);
    }

    keypresses++;;

    return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook, hookCode, vKeyCode, flags);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void InstallHook(void)
{
    hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, hInstance, 0);
}

__declspec(dllexport) int UninstallHook(void)
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
    hKeyboardHook = 0;
    return keypresses;
}
```

The Python code to use this is as follows:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = CDLL('C:\...\OurDLL.dll')
>>> dll.InstallHook()
```

[Type something at this point]

```
>>> result = dll.UninstallHook()
>>> result
0
```

EDIT: I should probably mention that I've also tried out a `LowLevelKeyboardHook`. I understand that the LowLevel hook is global and will catch all keystrokes, but that just caused my `dll.InstallHook()` Python code to freeze for a second or two before returning zero.

I am no expert in C, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
```

SetWindowsHookEx requires a hModule - save the hModule from DllMain and pass it here. (You can pass NULL only if the thread id is your own thread.)

One exception to this is for the _LL hook types; these don't need a hmodule param since these hook don't inject into the target process - that's why your code using KEYBOARD_LL is 'succeeding'.

As for why it might be blocking when you use KEYBOARD_LL - docs for LowLevelKeyboardHookProc mention that the thread that installs the hook (ie. calls SetWindowsHookEx) must have a message loop, which you might not have in your python code.

Debugging tips: it looks like SetWindowsHookEx should be returning NULL (with GetLastError() returning a suitable error code); while developing code, using some combination of assert/printf/OutputDebugString as appropriate to check these return values is a good way to ensure that your assumptions are correct and give you some clues as to where things are going wrong.

BTW, one other thing to watch for with KEYBOARD vs KEYBOARD_LL: the KEYBOARD hook gets loaded into the target process - but only if it's the same bitness - so a 32-bit hook only sees keys pressed by other 32-bit processes. OTOH, KEYBOARD_LL is called back in your own process, so you get to see all keys - and also don't need to deal with the shared segment (though as far as I know it's also less efficient as a KEYBOARD hook).

Comment: You're right! I needed to save the `HMODULE` type from DLLMain. It is now incrementing my `keypresses` value in the `KeyboardProc` callback function. The shared segment was code left over from when I was attempting the Lowlevel keyboard. Apologies for my sloppy code, I am ashamed of it, but I'll be fixing it up before I actually start using it. Again, many thanks!